# Calculate sum values from subreturn return variables

Tags: jasper-reports

I have text field with the following content.:

```
( $F{tckopf_R_ART}.equals( "1" ) && $V{euroFollowOnCommission} != null
) ? $V{charterEuroWorth} + $V{euroFollowOnCommission} : (
$F{tckopf_R_ART}.equals( "2" ) && $V{euroFollowOnCommission} != null )
? $V{charterEuroWorth} + $V{euroFollowOnCommission} : (
$F{tckopf_R_ART}.equals( "1" ) && $V{euroFollowOnCommission} == null )
? $V{charterEuroWorth} : ( $F{tckopf_R_ART}.equals( "2" ) &&
$V{euroFollowOnCommission} == null ) ? $V{charterEuroWorth} : null
```

where are `charterEuroWorth` and `euroFollowOnCommission` variables are `sum` calculations from 2 different subreports.

If I put above code to a new variable in the main report, I get `null` in the text field on the main report. I need to put it in variable in the main report, because also I need to calculate the `sum` value from the above code for every record in the main report.

I don't know, how I can achieve it. Maybe there is a problem with the variable properties? Please let me know, if you need further information.

How can I calculate the `sum` value from the above code for every record in the main report?

Comment: Depending on when the textfield is evaluated, the variable value could change. What is the evaluation time for the text field? This is an attribute in the textfield.

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/EvaluationTimeEnum.html

Comment: The text field evaluation is set to "Band".